Максимум призов - какое слово главное для зависимого определения
прошу помочь разобраться с числом определения, которое стоит после словосочетания с "максимум":
Это максимум призов, который (или которые) могут получить победители.

Если хочется максимум выделить, можно написать "это призовой максимум". Это призовой максимум, который лотерея могла предложить участникам.

Правильно:
Это максимум призов, которые могут получить победители.
Пояснение

Нормой считаться согласование союзного слова с ближайшим существительным, в то же время нужно проверить семантику такой отнесенности.

Проверка смысла:  Это призы, которые могут получить победители. Это максимум тех призов, которые могут получить победители.

По смыслу подходят оба варианта, поэтому выбираем ближайшее согласование.


ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Розенталь §210. Ошибки в сложных предложениях

Неправильный порядок слов в сложном предложении с придаточным определительным порождает двузначность или искажает смысл высказывания. Например, в предложении «Студенты проходили практику в одном из цехов завода, который недавно был реконструирован» – союзное слово который может иметь двоякую соотнесенность (был реконструирован один из цехов или завод в целом?), хотя по правилу слова который, какой, чем замещают ближайшее к ним существительное в форме того же рода и числа.

Правка в одних случаях достигается заменой придаточного предложения причастным оборотом. Ср.: 1) ...в одном из цехов завода, недавно реконструированном; 2) в одном из цехов завода, недавно реконструированного.
В других случаях в главное предложение вводится указательное местоимение тот или такой, соотносительное союзному слову который или какой, например: Посетители выставки подолгу задерживались у тех картин молодых художников, которые отражают непосредственную связь с современностью.
